# Textmate Regex Find Replace Help

Tags: php, regex, replace, find, textmate

I've got a project I'm working on converting some legacy perl cgi forms to PHP.  A lot of this requires finding / replacing information.  In one such case, I have lines like this in the perl script:

```
<INPUT type="radio" name="trade" value="1" $checked{trade}->{1}>
```

which needs to read:

```
<INPUT type="radio" name="trade" value="1" <?php echo checked('trade', 1); ?>>
```

Another example to show some variation in how these tags might show up in the perl/html:

```
<INPUT type="radio" name="loantype" value="new" $checked{loantype}->{new}>
<INPUT type="radio" name="loantype" value="new" $checked{'loantype'}->{new}>
<INPUT type="radio" name="loantype" value="new" $checked{'loantype'}->{'new'}>
<INPUT type="radio" name="loantype" value="new" $checked{loantype}->{'new'}>
```

As you can see, the quotes can be about anywhere, but that's not my problem.  I decided to write a find / replace regex in textmate to make my life a bit easier.  My Regex looks like:

```
Find:     \$checked\{'?([^']+)'?\}->\{'?([^']+)'?\}
Replace:  <?php echo checked('$1', '$2'); ?>
```

This worked fine in the first file I did it with, but for some reason in the current file the Regex has become really greedy, matching many lines.  it'll match the begininng (\$checked...) and then match up to the last time the character '}' appears.  I've tried a few variations to make it a bit less greedy including:

```
 ^(.*)\$checked\{'?([^']+)'?\}->\{'?([^']+)'?\}(.*)$
```

But even that seems to match multiple lines.  I assumed the ^ at the beginning would only match the beginning of a line, and the $ at the end would only match the end... constraining my match to 1 line... but it doesn't it seems.

/me fails at regex

Thanks for any help,
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(.*?)\$checked\{'?([^']+?)'?\}->\{'?([^']+?)'?\}(.*?)$
```

The `?` after `*` and `+` make them "non-greedy".